# SQL Server Static Function (drag down)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say if I have a table that looks like this:

```
Row        Account #

1          5500

2

3          6600

4

x...
```

So what I'd want to do is drag down the "5500" Account # to auto fill until a new Account # value is encountered (like 6600) and then drag that number down until another new Account # is encountered and so on (how many times they need to be dragged is variable).

Does SQL server have something like a static function for this? Not sure what's the best way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `outer apply()` to get the most recent non `null` value `Account`, and `isnull()` to use the current `Account`, or the most recent previous `Account` if `Account` is `null`.

```
select 
    t.row
  , Account = isnull(t.Account,x.Account)
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 i.Account
    from t as i
    where i.row < t.row
      and i.Account is not null
    order by row desc
  ) as x
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JADDMP41018

returns:

```
+-----+---------+
| row | Account |
+-----+---------+
|   1 |    5500 |
|   2 |    5500 |
|   3 |    6600 |
|   4 |    6600 |
+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_number to get rowpart and then sum by that partition as below

```
;with cte as (
    select *, RowPart = sum(RowN) over(order by Rowid) from ( 
    select *, RowN = case when accountno is not null then row_number() over(order by rowid) else 0 end  from #yourAccount
    ) a
) select RowId, sum(accountNo) over(partition by RowPart) from cte
```

Your input query:

```
create table #yourAccount(Rowid int, AccountNo int)


insert into #youraccount(Rowid,        AccountNo) values
 (1   ,       5500  )
,(2   ,     NULL    )
,(3   ,       6600  )
,(4   ,       NULL  )

insert into #youraccount(Rowid,        AccountNo) values
 (5   ,       null  )
,(6   ,     7700    )
,(7   ,       null  )
,(8   ,       NULL  )
,(9   ,       null  )
```